# Create private List View using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, list-view

Is it possible to create private list view (equivalent to list view with "Only I can see this list view" option selected when creating via UI) using Metadata API? If I create such list view using the UI and then retrieve the corresponding object from the org, the private view is not retrieved, so I have no idea what field determines if a view is private or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, unfortunately it's not possible:

> List views with the Visible only to me Restrict Visibility option are not accessible in Metadata API. Each of these list views is associated with a particular user.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm